# Javascript - replace string between brackets, but the brackets should stay

Tags: javascript, replace

I'd like to replace character inside a string, e.g.

Drafts [**2**]

To:

Drafts [**3**]

This regex returns only Drafts **3**:

```
str.replace(/\[(.+?)\]/g, 3)
```

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Do you need something more than below?

```
 var num=2 // parse this from drafts [2]
 num++;
 var newstr=str.replace(/\[(.+?)\]/g, "["+num+"]")
```

Or the brackets can change to <> {} per input?

You can also give a function instead of the replace-string.

```
var str = "Drafts [2]";

function replacer(match, p1, p2, p3, offset, string) {
  return p1 + (1+parseInt(p2)) + p3;
}
var newstr=str.replace(/([\[(])(.+?)([\])])/g, replacer);
alert(newstr); // alerts "Drafts [3]"
```

Answer (score 7):

Use zero width *assertions* instead of actually matching the brackets.

**EDIT**: Javascript does not have lookbehind. :c

As a general solution, you could capture the surrounding content and put it back in the replacement string using backreferences.

```
str.replace(/(\[).+?(\])/g, "$13$2")
```

Alternatively, you could include hardcoded brackets in your replacement.

Comment: I'm getting "SyntaxError: invalid quantifier" - error points to the first slash

Comment: @PeterO. Ah yes, so it does. Forgot Javascript does not have lookbehind. Updated.

Comment: Yes, js do not support lookbehind. it only supports lookahead.

Comment: If your regex will **always** have $1==[ & $2==], why not hardcode it?

Comment: This is a more general solution. If for example the surrounding content was "aiuhsadas" and "asdasdas", hardcoding the values would be inconvenient.

Answer (score 5):

You could just add the brackets to the replacement text like this:

```
str.replace(/\[(.+?)\]/g, "["+3+"]")
```

Edit: If you need to do anything with the number in the brackets, you can use a function instead of the replacement text:

```
str.replace(/\[(.+?)\]/g, function(string, first){
  // string is the full result of the regex "[2]"
  //first is the number 2 from "draft [2]"
  return "["+(first++)+"]";
})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need such functionality more then once you may create function with **method borrowing** trick.

```
const args = {
    source: "Lorem [ipsum] dolor [sit] amet",
    prefix: `<i style="background-color:yellow">`,
    suffix: '</i>',
    global: true,
    deleteBrackets: true
}

const bracketsToTags = (args) => {
    const { source, prefix, suffix, global = true, deleteBrackets = false } = args;
    const reg = /\[(.+?)\]/;
    source.replace = ''.replace;
    return source.replace(new RegExp(reg, global ? 'g': ''), 
                             (withBrackets, withoutBrackets) => (
        `${prefix}${deleteBrackets ? withoutBrackets: withBrackets}${suffix}`
    ))
}
```

So, running function

```
bracketsToTags(args)
```

you'll get

```
"Lorem <i style="background-color:yellow">ipsum</i> dolor <i style="background-color:yellow">sit</i> amet"
```

PS: use 'React HTML Parser' for React - [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser)

Answer (score 0):

For a more robust solution do the following which will match any text, including spaces, between brackets. The regex is `/\[(.*?)\]/g`.

```js
var first = "This is a [1] test."
var second = "This [2] is also [three] a test."
var third = "This is [4.0a] also [five a] a test."

var result1 = first.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/g, replacer);
var result2 = second.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/g, replacer);
var result3 = third.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/g, replacer);

function replacer(text) {
  var str = "XXX" + text + "YYY";
    return str;
}
console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
console.log(result3);
```